# Query Custom Post Type Taxonomy term with multiple parameters

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type 'doctors'. Its posts are tied to a 'department' taxonomy (e.g. 'dentist', 'neurologist' etc.). Some 'doctors' are actually a joint practice, and in order to have the separate doctors that are subsumed under a joint practice post still appear in search results, they are listed separately as well (e.g.: there is a post 'John & Miller', plus two separate posts for 'Dr. John' and 'Dr. Miller') respectively. The two single-doctor posts have a [relationship field via Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) 'jointpractice' pointing to the joint practice post and are redirecting there.

For the display of taxonomy terms, e.g. overview of all Dentists, the project requires that all single doctors and joint practices are listed alphabetically, but all single doctors belonging to a joint practice be 'grouped' with the joint practice.

- Dr. Anton
- Dr. Beta
- John & Miller [joint practice post]
- — Dr. John
- — Dr. Miller
- Dr. Kraft
- Dr. Seemethrough
  […]

Is there an easy way to query posts like described above, excluding the joint-practice’s single posts from the alphabetical order, and then group them alphabetically after their joint practice post like above?

Comment: why not make the "department" field multi-select. Dr john could be a member of as many departments as he wants and would still show up in the individual related searches.  Would also give him wider audience instead of penalizing him for for being multi-department.

Comment: Hi there, don't know if I get you right :), but as the department is a taxonomy, Dr John is already able to appear in multiple taxonomy terms/departments. What I am after is handling joint practices and their respective single doctors that have their own posts as described above ;). What puts a relation between them is a custom field on the single doctor’s posts pointing to the joint practice post.

Comment: i think i may have been mis-reading.  can you make one of your department choices "joint practice"?  This could then open a 2nd relation field that would allow you to choose 2 other doctors.  from there the coding would be fairly simple...

Comment: No problem :). As the project requires me to list both the joint practices and the single doctors for each department, making 'joint practice' a department as well might not fit right into it, especially because it means something different than the other departments (type of practice vs. type of profession).

Comment: i'm sure there is a way to make it work.  let me know if you want to troubleshoot more.

Comment: I’m actually not much further than before, since your approach sadly doesn’t seem to help me to differentiate between the practices and build a query the way I described above ;). Thanks for your help anyway.